# Fetch mysql data with different operators

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to fetch data from a database adding a dot into it using MySQL?

e.g. If I've data inserted into a DB such as 'BA', after fetching the value can I display it as B.A?

Can I also change something from L_T to something like L/T?

Thanks

Comment: Feeling the need to do this on the database level _might_ indicate an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Might, or might not .... ;-)

Comment: You want to achive _X_ and figured out a way _Y_ to do this. Now you've asked us how to do _Y_ . If you'd explain _X_ you _might_ get a better answer.

Comment: simply i want to insert my data into db like this b.a which is not possible so i m sending it like ba and i want to fetch the data like b.a .. that's my query

Comment: "simply i want to insert my data into db like this b.a which is not possible" - Now, _that's_ strange. Why sholdn't you be able to add a value containing a dot to a mysql table?

Comment: got it .. :( n sorry .. got back to my computer after a year .. seems to have forgotten a lot of things ..

Answer (score 1):

In case of `BA` to `B.A` do something like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(YOURCOLUMN, 1) + '.' + RIGHT(YOURCOLUMN, 1) FROM YOURTABLE
```

And for the other one I will let you guess :)

Comment: Yes! The query is not doing more then select the very first char, append it with "." (or anything you want) and append it with the very last char.

Comment: and if it will be some 4 or 5 digit  word ?? i just ve to change the last value ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `php`

```
 $db_cecord = "BA";
 $formatted = implode('.',str_split($db_record));
```

This will result in `B.A`

Answer (score 0):

For the second part use

```
SELECT REPLACE(YOURCOLUMN, '_', '/') AS YOURCOLUMN
```

This will replace any instance of `_` with `/` in results for the selected column.  If you exclude the `AS YOURCOLUMN` the row name in the results would be `replace(YOURCOLUMN, '_', '/')`